# Openshift oc tools & web ui are timing out: Error from server (ServerTimeout)

Tags: openshift, openshift-3

A simple command like below is timing out continuously

```
oc get pods
```

Error from server (ServerTimeout): the server cannot complete the requested operation at this time, try again later

My network connectivity is fine. I have been working with openshift for more than a year, but have not seen this. It started happening from 8th of June 2018.

[image: Web UI errors]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What OpenShift cluster is this? Your own, your companies, Minishift, OpenShift Online?

Comment: It is openshift online

Comment: Two possibilities. The first is that the web console can rely on websocket connections. If there is a loss of the connection due to timeout, you can see that. If you refresh the web console page it should be fine. The second possibility is that your login session timed out. The login session on Online Starter is one 1 day (not sure about Pro). In that case if you refresh you would be asked to login again.

Comment: Understand both reasons, I open a new session every time so that cannot be an issue. The timeout has started happening very frequently (approximately 1/15 requests succeed), this was never the case before. Just for additional information, I am accessing it from India. Even the browser based UI gives same errors on refresh (tried multiple times).

Comment: What browser and OS are you using? Which specific OpenShift Online cluster is it?

Comment: Windows 10 & 8, google chrome browser. The cluster is Canada.

Comment: It seems to be working fine today. Thanks for your help. Any idea, what was the issue?

Comment: No idea. They have been doing various software updates on the Starter clusters, so it may have been due to that.

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your time. Really appreciate it!